# How to sweeten my pasteurised apple juice?

Tags: sweetness

I’ve bottled and pasteurised some apple juice and it’s a bit “tart” this year. What should I use to sweeten it?

Any tips for avoiding this again next year while
I’m bottling?

TIA

Comment: any sugar with 0 taste

Answer (score 1):

If it's pasteurised, sweeten it with whatever you like. If you're worried you're going to introduce more yeast with the sweetener, just pasteurise it again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

For sweetening apple juice, fructose would seem the sugar of choice.